# "DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned." in FireFox 34

Tags: javascript, local-storage, mozilla, postmessage

Using given function to post message, but getting error "DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned." at Line "target['postMessage'](message, target_url.replace( /([^:]+://[^/]+).*/, '$1'));" in FireFox-34, same code is working fine on Chrome and older version of FireFox.

```
var storage = function() {
    return {
           postMessage : function(message, target_url, target) {
           if (!target_url) { 
              return; 
           }
           var target = target || parent;  // default to parent
           if (target['postMessage']) { 
                   // the browser supports window.postMessage, so call it with a targetOrigin
                   // set appropriately, based on the target_url parameter.
                   target['postMessage'](message, target_url.replace( /([^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+).*/, '$1'));
               }               
         }
    }
}();
```

Comment: What is the type of "message" that is trying to be posted when the error occurs?  Blob or File maybe?

Comment: If the `message` variable being passed includes DOM node objects such as a `DocumentFragment` object, you'll need to convert it to a string using the `XMLSerializer.prototype.serializeToString` method before sending. You can use a `DOMParser` object or the `Element.prototype.innerHTML`, `Element.prototype.insertAdjacentHTML`, or `Element.prototype.outerHTML` methods to unserialize the object on the other end.

Answer (score 15):

[`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) sends messages using the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm) in Firefox and because of that there are certain things you need to adjust prior to sending.

In your example it isn't obvious what message contains but one hack-y way around structured clone is to coerce a bit. Sending a URL via `postMessage` will throw an error:

```
someWindow.postMessage(window.location, '*');
// ERROR
```

But you can do this to work around it:

```
var windowLocation = '' + window.location;
someWindow.postMessage(windowLocation, '*');
// WORKS
```

There are better ways to handle this but for what you've provided this should at least allow consistent behavior.

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer which lead me to the string conversion solving my problem, I'd suggest simply using `window.location.href` which is the value the "tostring" method would be referencing, thank you.